# Enter key to display toast text is not working on edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, toast, enter

I am using Intellij IDEA 11, Android 4.1 and using the example in http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-textbox-example/ to display toast text after a user enters a text in the edit text then presses enter. The problem is that the enter key always creates a new line, the keyboard is still there and the toast is not displayed. I'm using emulator ARM with skin WVGA800 to test this if that makes any difference.

I tried diffrent things including:

```
edittext.requestFocus(); 
edittext.setFocusable(true);
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); and
edittext.setMaxLines(1);
```

but it is still not working.

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class T_C_Activity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    private EditText edittext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addKeyListener();
    }

    public void addKeyListener() {

        // get edittext component
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        //edittext.setFocusable(true);
        //edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        //edittext.setMaxLines(1);

        // add a keylistener to keep track user input
        edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    edittext.requestFocus();
                    // display a floating message
                    Toast.makeText(T_C_Activity.this,
                            edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    return true;

                } else if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9)) {
                    edittext.requestFocus();
                    // display a floating message
                    Toast.makeText(T_C_Activity.this,
                            "Number 9 is pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [imeOptions section](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) of the API documentation.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_name"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:editable="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                android:focusable="true"
                />
```

Then, You can listen for editor events like this:

```
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO){
                      //do whatever you want
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```